# ! Package inputenc Error: Unicode character α (U+03B1)

Tags: errors, unicode, greek, letters

I try running Texmaker on a new pc and I get multiple errors when trying to use greek letters. I use the same packages as my old pc which worked fine but now I get these errors.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[top=2.54cm, bottom=2.54cm, left=1.91cm, right=1.91cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[version=3]{mhchem}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsbsy}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{mathrsfs,amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{slashed}
\usepackage{tensor}
\usepackage{braket}
\usepackage{graphbox}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[english,greek]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage[LGR, T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\babeltags{en = english}
\usepackage[style=ieee,backend=bibtex,autolang=other]{biblatex}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\begin{document}
ασδσαδα


\end{document}
```

The errors i get are these:

> ! Package inputenc Error: Unicode character α (U+03B1)(inputenc) not
>   set up for use with LaTeX.See the inputenc package documentation for
>   explanation.Type H  for immediate help.... α
>
> ! Package inputenc Error: Unicode character σ (U+03C3)(inputenc) not
>   set up for use with LaTeX.See the inputenc package documentation for
>   explanation.Type H  for immediate help.... ασ
>
> ! Package inputenc Error: Unicode character δ (U+03B4)(inputenc) not
>   set up for use with LaTeX.See the inputenc package documentation for
>   explanation.Type H  for immediate help.... ασδ
>
> ! Package inputenc Error: Unicode character δ (U+03B4)(inputenc) not
>   set up for use with LaTeX.See the inputenc package documentation for
>   explanation.Type H  for immediate help.... ασδσαδ

Comment: Compiles with no issues for me. Are you sure the MWE is saved as utf8?

Comment: Are you using miktex? In miktex support for LGR is broken. https://github.com/MiKTeX/miktex-packaging/issues/114

Comment: I am using Texmaker

Comment: daleif, I dont know how to check that...

Comment: texmaker is an editor not a tex system. Look in the log-file if it says "miktex" somewhere.

Comment: Yes i am using Miktex, but I was using Miktex also on my old pc,where there where no issues
EDIT: I see now that this is a new error in Miktex.

Comment: Is there any solution to this?

Comment: get lgrenc.dfu from here http://mirrors.ctan.org/language/greek/greek-inputenc/lgrenc.dfu and put it in the folder of your document. And add a remark to the miktex issue that the problem still persist - it is easy to repair and I wonder why it doesn't happen.